# Redirect click on table cell to <a> in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that has quite large cells and there's link in some of them (a little button to be exact).

I want a click on the whole cell to trigger a click of the little button.

Here's what I tried but it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $a = $this.find('a');
        if ($a) {
            $this.css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function () {
                $a.click();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
td {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><td><a href="page">L</a></td>
        <td><a href="hello">I</a></td>
        <td><a href="duckling">N</a></td>
        <td><a href="pizza">K</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

The style is applied all right, but a click on the cell causes a Stack Overflow error in jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `td` inside the `a` tag?

Comment: Can you style the `a` to be a block element that takes up the whole cell?  That's probably going to work better and as a bonus wouldn't require JavaScript.

Comment: @jakekimds: I believe that's invalid HTML...

Comment: @David that's true, but it won't work too good for me. It'll be a fallback solution.

Comment: Why wouldn't that work too good for you?

Comment: there's this button (<a>), a number in a span next to it etc.. I'll have to change a lot of styles to implement this.

Comment: I don't follow. Is the code you've posted above not a true example of your problem? Seems fixable with CSS only. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ma31nnnn/

Comment: yeah I'll probably do that as the jquery solution is clumsy and still not working right. thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happend here is that when you call $a.click(), it will also call td's click event because of event propagation, hence creating an infinite loop.

So for this case you need to add some extra check inside your td's click event, you should only trigger child  tag's click event when event.target (source of the click event) is the 'td', not 'a'.

Put my word in code:

```
$('td').on("click",function (ev) {
    if(ev.target.tagName ==='TD'){
       $(this).find("a").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

See my fiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tLd4rkdc/
By the way, I would suggest you to use developer tools (hit F12 in IE/Firefox/Chrome) or use FireBug to debug your javascript. If you turned on the debug console you would know what's going on very easily.

Comment: I think I accidentally used someone's fiddle link to put my code instead of creating one....I'll create a new one later

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the click event handler directly on the `td`:

   ```
   $('td').click(function (event) {

   });
   ```
2. Find the `a` element within the cell and trigger a click on it:

   ```
   $(this).find('a').click();
   ```
3. Stop the propagation of the event, if clicked directly on the `a` to suppress a loop:

   ```
   $('td a').click(function (event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
   });
   ```

I prepared a complete fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldp31krg/8/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // prevent the propagation of the click event on the a, to avoid a click loop
  $('td a').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('td').click(function (event) {
    $(this).find('a').click();
  });
});
```

**hint**: if you want the cell look like a link in CSS, add a cursor rule:

```
td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

See in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldp31krg/2/

Comment: Will it help to use stopPropagation like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldp31krg/8/

Answer (score 0):

You dont need javascript for resolve Your problem.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54yk6wdc/)

Try to set padding for `a` elements inside `td`.

```
td {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

a {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

But if You still want `jQuery` solution - [Check this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54yk6wdc/3/).

If this is still not what are You looking, check my next solution with support for `href` and `target` attributes - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54yk6wdc/5/).